# What belongs in site.pp, and what should be moved out of it?

Tags: puppet

So far I've been putting everything in site.pp. This causes the file to become long and cluttered.

Should I be doing this, or should I move stuff out of site.pp and into external files, and then somehow reference those files from within site.pp?

Comment: This feels like it should be asked on [sf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very little belongs in site.pp, there's usually a better place for it that's more manageable.

1. Individual resources (files, services, packages, cron entries etc.) should all be moved into classes per component/service that you're managing. Try to break this down into logical components as much as possible, e.g. `apache` and `mysql` classes rather than a `lamp` role class. ([docs: Language: Classes](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html))
2. Classes should be moved into modules. Modules are a way of containing related classes (e.g. `apache::service` with `apache`), providing Puppet a way to efficiently find classes without loading every file, and to contain related files and templates. Your Apache class might then live in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/apache/manifests/init.pp` or similar. ([docs: Module Fundamentals](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html))
3. Node definitions and class parameters can be moved into Hiera or an node node classifier (ENC). Using Hiera, you'd perhaps use `hiera_include` ([docs: Assigning Classes to Nodes With Hiera](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.1/puppet.html#assigning-classes-to-nodes-with-hiera-hierainclude)) to add classes to nodes, and regular Hiera data to store class parameters ([docs: Automatic Parameter Lookup](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup)). ENCs are external scripts and could query whatever data source you already have, or are supplied by other applications such as [Foreman](http://theforeman.org).
4. Resource defaults might still remain in site.pp to apply to every node and class.